# How to pass two String arrays using Ajax call MVC4

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, function, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to pass two string arrays from the view to controller using Ajax.But while passing it shows the error 
**jquery-latest.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:5342/Purchase/ClearCart 500 (Internal Server Error)**
The Method is not passing to the controller.Tried with a break point.Here is how am passing string[]

```
 var items = $('.mids').map(function () {
        return $(this).val()
    }).get();
    var counts = $('.counts').map(function () {
        return $(this).val()
    }).get();



 if (BOLT.response.txnStatus == 'SUCCESS') {

                    alert("success");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Purchase/ClearCart",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        //dataType: "text",
                        data: { mid: items, count: counts },
                        success: function (result) {
                            alert("success");
                        },

                        error: function (e) {
                            alert("Failed");
                        }
                    });
```

It returns "Failed" response and the above error.

> Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public void ClearCart(string[] mid,string[] count)
        {
        int uid=Convert.ToInt32(Session["uid"]);
        userService.ClearCart(uid, mid,count);

        }
```

Here is the values inside Mid and count:[image: Values inside Mid and count]

Comment: Can you show the exact value of `data: { mid: items, count: counts }`? We need to see that so we could make a model for it.

Comment: @Jerdine Sabio updated my question.Am just puting the values (mid,count) in two lists

Comment: Because you're not passing in json.  Remove `contentType: "application/json",`

Comment: You are sending a single object from your jquery, in your controller get these parameters in a Map and then retrieve the values using keys mid and count

Comment: OH okay, to clarify those are just string arrays yes?

Comment: @Jerdine Sabio now the ajax calling to the controller is working fine,But parameter returns null

Comment: Can you include the data from mid and count? `Console.log(items)` `Console.log(counts)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved With @Jerdine Sabio 's answer with some adjustment.

```
 var clr = new Object();
    clr.mid = items;
    clr.count = counts;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Purchase/ClearCart",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: JSON,
        data: JSON.stringify(clr),
        success: function (result) {
            alert("success");
        },

        error: function (e) {
            alert("Failed");
        }
    });
```

in The Controller

```
 public class SampleModel
        {
            public string[] mid { get; set; }
            public string[] count { get; set; }
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult ClearCart(SampleModel model)
        {

        int[] matids = Array.ConvertAll(model.mid, int.Parse);
        int[] mcounts = Array.ConvertAll(model.count, int.Parse);

          //rest of the code
        }
```

Comment: Mark yours as the answer so this could be closed. Good job.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the values to an object during POST.

1. Create a Class to be bound

```
public class AjaxModel{
   public List<int> mid {get;set;}
   public List<int> count {get;set;}

   // Alternatively, try list string
   // public List<string> mid {get;set;}
   // public List<string> count {get;set;}
}
```

2. Modify the ClearCart to include `AjaxModel model` on the parameters

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ClearCart(AjaxModel model)
{
   return Content(model.mid.Count())

   // int uid=Convert.ToInt32(Session["uid"]);
   // userService.ClearCart(uid, model.mid, model.count);
}
```

3. Modify ajax call to include `contentType: application/json`

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/Purchase/ClearCart",
   type: "POST",
   contentType: "application/json",
   data: { mid: items, count: counts },
   success: function (result) {
      alert("success");
   },
   error: function (e) {
      alert("Failed");
   }
});
```

Comment: tried but its shows an error "has some invalid argument"

Comment: @codeseeker Can you include the data from mid and count? `Console.log(items)` `Console.log(counts)` I assumed they were list string, looks like they may not be

Comment: Sir,Added a screen Shot.Please have a look

Comment: @codeseeker I updated the class to use List<int>, I also changed the return type of the function to ActionResult for testing. Try it now

Comment: Got the answer sir,Thank You